# Running a function rapidly in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a function as so.

```
sub main {
    my $item;
    $send = item_id();
    $send .= item_id2();
    $send .= jobproccess();
    send_idea($send) && send_idea($send) && send_idea($send);
}
```

so as you can see, its running the function send_idea multiple times.
how can i do that in one line.

send_idea($send) x 4 &&

is there any possible way of doing that.

Comment: Your code doesn't necessarily run 'send_idea' multiple times.  It only does if the return value from 'send_idea' is non-zero.  Is that what you wanted or is it ok just to run it multiple times regardless of the return value?

Comment: @TLP shows how to solve this problem no matter which one you meant, so you can probably disregard my comment.  Leaving it here though just to make it clear that it's something you should think about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a simple loop

```
send_idea($send) for 1 .. 3;
```

Which is the post-script version of

```
for (1 .. 3) {
    send_idea($send);
}
```

But of course, there is a hidden dynamic here. The `&&` operator does more than just chain commands together. It checks the return value of your subroutine `send_idea()` and if one of them fails, the others do not get executed. So if you want that functionality included, you would need something like

```
for (1 .. 3) {
    send_idea($send) or last;
}
```

This can also be written

```
send_idea($send) or last for 1 .. 3;
```

In your question, your statement is chained with `&&`, but in fact it should be just three separate statements, unless you want this check included.

```
send_idea($send);
send_idea($send);
send_idea($send);
```

Your title mentions "rapidly", which is very different from running a function in a way that looks nice in the code. If speed is what you want, anything you do in this end of the calling procedure is going to have negligible effect on the outcome.

Comment: where did `|| last for ..` go? :)

Comment: @mpapec I changed it to be like the other `for` loop because I realized that when using parentheses, you do not need the higher precedence of `||`.